# How to optimize storage of this data in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Let's look at this database structure

```
Iterations
    id (primary key)
    start (timestamp)
    end (timestamp nullable)

Items
  id (primary key)
  title (text)
  foreign_id (integer)
  location (point nullable)
  some other text fields

Iteration_items
     iteration_id (foreign key to iterations(id))
     item_id (foreign key to items(id))
```

Every hour

```
1. Create new record in `iterations` with `start` equals to now
2. Do some processing and store about 5000 records in `items` table (plus 5000 records in `iteration_items`), so every `iteration` contains about 5000 items.
3. After it is done set `end` to now for latest `iteration`
```

Problem: every `iteration` (mostly in `items` table) takes about 100Mb of disk data, I can not zip this data in some way (there is some text in it).

There can be multiple duplicates:

```
1. Iteration 34 contains item with foreign id 837435.
2. Iteration 35 contains item with foreign id 837453
3. ...
4. Iteration 42 DOES not contain item with foreign id 837453
```

Data in item with foreign id 837435 can be changed between iterations.

For example:

```
   iteration 34
       point(1.1,2.2)
       title 'some example text'
   iteration 35
       point(1.1, 2.3)
       title 'another example text'
```

I need to store this data so that later it can be compared.

How to deal with continuosly growing database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a fast growing database is not "problematic", so to speak, especially when the structure is sound, like yours. On the other hand, when you say "store this data so that it can be compared later" feels like you might need an analytical database to complement your MySql one. This type of software is designed to store huge amount of data (without taking enormous amount of disk space) and query them lightning fast.

Maybe you should consider storing only the most recent data in your MySql Database and periodically sync with a Data Warehouse. That would probably scale much better.

Have a look at this article, it has some nice suggestions:

[Choosing a Database](https://segment.com/blog/choosing-a-database-for-analytics/)

Also, here are a few personal ones you could consider:

Infobright: MySql's datawarehousing solution. Free community edition that only allows you to insert data, not modify it. Integrates perfectly with MySql.

PostgreSQL: Not typically a data warehouse, but can still handle huge loads of data really well and keep performance at a decent level.

Vertica: HP's solution, has a free community edition. Super fast and powerful, but can be difficult to integrate with some things like PHP (the one we currently use where I work).